# Slots Booking Module In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a booking module.I have the available Time duration Slots store in an state `available_time=["10:20","11:30","11:30" ]`.

I am getting `max_slots = number` from api.

Now i am trying to populate Data in row and column, like:

```
10:30 :- Slots 1, slots 2, slots 3
11:30 :- Slots 1, slots 2, slots 3
```

Slots could be 1, 2 or anything if there is one max_slot then I need to set the width of slot 100% if it's more then 2 then set the width half.I have tried doing it but it seems like i am missing something essential.

Attaching the link of my JS fiddle [right here](https://jsfiddle.net/pritamKumar/8zok6tpq/3/).

Comment: jsfiddle.net/pritamKumar/8zok6tpq/3/ JS fiddle Link.

Comment: Not sure why code is not working on JsFiddle. But seems to working here without any issues:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qzp1jl2olj

Comment: Hi @logeekal , but i need those slots in column.

Comment: Check this out: I think this is what you need. https://codesandbox.io/s/qzp1jl2olj

I achieved it via flexbox CSS. Please check. I did a little modification in the script to generate random slots;

Comment: yes exactly thank you.Can we put onClick method on every item in column.It would be great if you could help me out i am fairly new to Reactjs.Thank you.!

Comment: Slots Would be equal in every column, we have different logic for enable & disable slots.I just needed while(i<max_slot) {i++} max_slot could be any number.